Error when importing DWG file in QGIS
In QGIS 3.34.9 I am trying to import a DWG file (from Autodesk AutoCAD 2019) into QGIS using the Import tool (Project > Import/Export > Import files from DWG/DXF), but I can´t.

What am I doing wrong?

Looks like you're trying to convert the DWG to GPKG. Have you tried just importing the DWG?

By the error message QGIS does not support DWG format version 2018/2019/2020. Can you save data from AutoCAD into older version and try again? Or use DXF instead?

The error message is pretty clear, this tool cannot read AutoCAD 2018/2019/2020 document and you state that you are trying to import an AutoCAD 2019....

You can use free online tools or Autodesk DWG Viewer (also free) to save the .dwg to an earlier version.

thanks all, the problem has been solved

Please post how you solved it and mark as Solution.
